# numpy scipy -- keep eigenvalues in stringent order

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I compute the eigenvalues of a time-dependent matrix using scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(matrix) for each point in time. Then I collect them in a nested list ([[result for time 1], [result for time 2], etc.] and store the list via numpy.savetxt.

My problem is that so far I have not been able to find a way how, when I read the results from my file and plot them, I can avoid a "mixing up" of the values. Whenever two eigenvalues (corresponding to energy levels) cross each other in time, what happens to my plot is that the line that is drawn automatically switches. So the lowest energy level is for example always drawn as a solid line, even though at one point what was initially the lowest level becomes the second-to-lowest one and the initial second-to-lowest (maybe drawn as a dashed line) then is the lowest level. So you can see in the plot where the solid line would be supposed to become the second-to-lowest and the dashed should be the lowest, but at that point the lines "exchange" style.

My idea for fixing the problem was something to like calculating the slope of the lines and rearrange the elements of the results for each point in time accordingly so that for example the first item in each sublist would correspond to what was initially the lowest eigenvalue. But I couldn't find an easy and systematic way to do this in spite of having looked for similar problems all over the internet, so I really hope someone has maybe had a similar problem and found some feasible solution for it.

Comment: Yeah this is a common issue you run into when eigendecomposing a sequence of matrixes. There is no easy mathematical solution and you have to resort to hacks like you mentioned, detecting when two sequences cross. I've usually chosen to *not* show multiple sequences of eigenvalues in one plot for this reason, and broken them out to different plots (I was usually able to keep track of them using eigenvectors).

Comment: Here's a poor man's tracker, simplified for clarity: assume you have a sequence of `N` 2x2 matrixes, so you have `N` pairs of eigenvalues. Assume that the two eigenvalues don't switch order in the first 5 (out of `N`) or so points. Fit a spline to the five points, extrapolate where the sixth would be, find the sixth eigenvalue closest to that predicted point, and assign that one to this track. With M>2 eigenvalues, you'd do this M-1 times, assigning M-1 eigenvalues to M-1 "tracks", assigning the last one to the one remaining track. Put the code on Github so the rest of us can use it ;)

Comment: Thank's Ahmed for your suggestion, I'll try and fix it that way. I had hoped for a more simple solution but at least maybe my code will help others facing the same issue.

Comment: You might also consider tracking the corresponding eigenvectors, which should vary continuously. It is likely that by finding the eigenvector at time (t-1) closest to the current eigenvector, you can determine which eigenvalues belong to which sequence.